# Using supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in appdelegate to restrict orientation

Tags: objective-c, uikit

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
{
    NSInteger skipforeground;
    NSInteger allowLandscape;
    NSInteger NoCheck;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *) application
  supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *) window {
   
    
    if (self->allowLandscape) {
        NSLog(@"rotation yes !");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    };
 

}
```

If I set self->allowLandscape to true elsewhere in the code and try to rotate my iphone, "rotation yes" will show up in the debugger window but the screen won't rotate.

If I replace the "self->allowLandscape" condition by "2>1" it will work.

How come both times the return is the same but one works and the other won't ?